# QT not working CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is not defined, you may need to set it,CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:20 (find_package):

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I need to use qt for a college assignment and my qt doesn't work, I've reinstalled my mingw compiler and qt show me a bunch of errors when i make a new qt console executable project
This is the code writen:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    qDebug() << "Hello World";
    return QCoreApplication::exec();
}
```

This is my CMake list:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(qttest3)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

set(QT_VERSION 5)
set(REQUIRED_LIBS Core)
set(REQUIRED_LIBS_QUALIFIED Qt5::Core)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

if (NOT CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH)
    message(WARNING "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is not defined, you may need to set it "
            "(-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=\"path/to/Qt/lib/cmake\" or -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/include/{host}/qt{version}/ on Ubuntu)")
endif ()

find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION} COMPONENTS ${REQUIRED_LIBS} REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${REQUIRED_LIBS_QUALIFIED})
if (WIN32)
    set(DEBUG_SUFFIX)
    if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES "Debug")
        set(DEBUG_SUFFIX "d")
    endif ()
    set(QT_INSTALL_PATH "${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")
    if (NOT EXISTS "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/bin")
        set(QT_INSTALL_PATH "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/..")
        if (NOT EXISTS "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/bin")
            set(QT_INSTALL_PATH "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/..")
        endif ()
    endif ()
    if (EXISTS "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/plugins/platforms/qwindows${DEBUG_SUFFIX}.dll")
        add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory
                "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/plugins/platforms/")
        add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
                "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/plugins/platforms/qwindows${DEBUG_SUFFIX}.dll"
                "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/plugins/platforms/")
    endif ()
    foreach (QT_LIB ${REQUIRED_LIBS})
        add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
                "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/bin/Qt${QT_VERSION}${QT_LIB}${DEBUG_SUFFIX}.dll"
                "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>")
    endforeach (QT_LIB)
endif ()
```

And this is the errors i receive when loading the cmake list:

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:16 (message):
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is not defined, you may need to set it
  (-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="path/to/Qt/lib/cmake" or
  -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/include/{host}/qt{version}/ on Ubuntu)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:20 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5" with any of
  the following names:

    Qt5Config.cmake
    qt5-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/C Problems/qttest3/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I don't really understand what sould I do whit what the console gives me :(

Comment: Did you mean `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` instead of `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`?

Comment: On my box (which is running Windows), I set an environment variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to solve this issue. I have googled and done it once and already forgot how I found the right path. However, in my case it is `D:/Qt/5.15.1/msvc2019_64/lib/cmake`. It contains sub-directories for all the Qt modules which in turn contain just `.cmake` files. You seem to be on Windows as well but might use another platform. Hence, check `msvc2019_64` and replace it with the resp. platform dir. which is appropriate to your installation. I just looked into `D:/Qt/5.15.1` with the Explorer and found a variety.

Comment: _but might use another platform_ Sorry, you do. You mentioned at the beginning that you're using mingw. However, I saw `D:/Qt/5.15.1/mingw81_32` and `D:/Qt/5.15.1/mingw81_64` on my side. Hence, (a full Qt installation assumed) there should be something similar on your computer as well.